# excel: If I search for a MIN value in a range, and 2 values are MIN, it only displays the first

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a function where I look for the MIN value in a range, lets say 9, 18, 12, 9.
Both 9's are the MIN, but MIN only looks at the 'first' min value. 
I want to be able to also give the 2nd '9' in my range as an option, to make it more clear: The columns in which these values are represent a location, and the value itself represents how easy it is to go there, so if 2 locations have value '9', I want a way to not only display the first '9' column as a result, but also the 2nd '9' column since this result is just as valid. How can I address the 2nd value when using this function, so that my result shows both the first AND second column with these MIN values. IS there a way to exclude the already found MIN value in another MIN search? Or how would I address this 2nd 'min' value?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in column **A**
In **C1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$20)=MIN(A$1:A$20),ROW($A$1:$A$20),""),ROW()),"")
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

This will display the row number(s) of the cells containing the minimum value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the found values.  This code works for me.  Note the FindNext operation in the loop.

```
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(SrchVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    FirstFind = rngFound.Address
    Do
        'Do something with the found value
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
    Loop Until rngFound.Address = FirstFind
End If
```

Comment: I don't feel like this is the solution i'm looking for, since I've got a pretty big table and before I can find the MIN value of a range of 4numbers, I VLOOKUP wich row these values are, then perform the MIN function, THEN link this min value to it's corresponding column name to retrieve the location. How do I implement this inside those actions?

Comment: I don't know...  What you're asking for as I understand it is exactly what I am doing with the above example.  I search a range of multiple columns for the minimum value and then, in my case, highlight it.  You have to loop through all the locations of the minimum value with FindNext.  Sorry I don't better understand your problem.